# How to generate a big number of unique random numbers in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

In my project I need to generate a lots of (thousands) of unique random numbers. So far I am using this not-so-efficient solution:

```
public void codeFactory(int count) {
    for (;count > 0; count --) {
        while (true) {
            long code = getRandomCode();
            Long codeStored = em.select("c.code").from("codes c").where("c.code = ?", code)
                .fetchSingle(Long.class);
            if (codeStored == null) {
                // this code has not yet been stored
                break;
            } else {
                // we continue, this code is already stored
                continue;
            }
            ...
        }
        // we have created a unique code
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create them directly with MySQL so I would not need to access MySQL for each code?

EDIT:
I want to generate RANDOM numbers between 1000000000000 and 9999999999999.

Comment: All databases are capable of generating incremental indexes, check out auto_increment for mysql

Comment: "a big number of unique random numbers"... what exactly does that mean? for example: do you want to generate 1000 random numbers between 0 and 1?

Comment: Have you looked into [`rand()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)?

Comment: I want to generate RANDOM and UNIQUE numbers between 1000000000000 and 9999999999999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider:

1. Your table name as `TestTable`
2. You have to generate a random number between two numbers `min_num` and `max_number`
3. Random Number should be unique and would be stored in column `TestColumn`

you can do something like this

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (<max_number> - <min_num> + 1)) + <min_number> AS random_number
FROM TestTable 
WHERE "random_num" NOT IN (SELECT TestColumn FROM TestTable) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: So far the best answer, will wait to see if there is more, but then I will probably accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? A number of libraries exist to generate random numbers. Look at apache.commons.math3 for instance:

```
package com.techtrip.labs.stackoverflow;

import org.apache.commons.math3.random.ISAACRandom;

public class GeneralTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int[] seed = {19399213, 123219, 32132, 32838};
        ISAACRandom rndGen = new ISAACRandom(seed);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            System.out.println(String.format("The random value is %d", rndGen.nextLong()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL and my problem.

Comment: I realized that after I reread your description and that is why I gave the JPA solution. However the description of your problem is confusing, hence the comments by others and your clarification in your edit to the problem statement. 

The statement "Is there a way to create them directly with MySQL so I would not need to access MySQL for each code?" makes no sense at all. 

However, if you are looking for a way to generate the random numbers in MySql I though that the answer by Hitesh above was good.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it generically using JPA and a sequence generator if your goal is to generate unique ids; there are a number of strategies.

For example, very simplistic:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
..
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
...
    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "Something")
public class Something extends AbstractEntity {
... // rest of Something Body
}

public interface SomethingRepository extends CrudRepository<Something, Long>{

}

// Simple test using initializing bean 
@Component
public class SomethingTest implements InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    SomethingRepository sRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            sRepo.save(new Something());
        }

        Iterator<Something> i = sRepo.findAll().iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Something s = i.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("Next random sequence num %d", s.getId()));
        }
    }
}
```